# onpointercancel not triggered in Edge when user touches and scrolls the win-list item together

Tags: microsoft-edge, winjs

We are building for latest Edge browser and I am seeing the issue where when user touches and scrolls a win-list item, the item turns grey and no other item is invoke-able anymore. I have created a plunker with latest WinJS libraries to help reproduce.

This works fine on Chrome but fails on EdgeHTML 18.1.17763

https://plnkr.co/edit/xtEyGOjb1wgbNspx?p=preview

```
<div class="listView win-selectionstylefilled"
         data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
         data-win-options="{
                    itemDataSource: Sample.ListView.data.dataSource,
                    itemTemplate: select('.smallListIconTextTemplate'),
                    selectionMode: 'none',
                    tapBehavior: 'none',
                    layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }
            }">
    </div>
```

Steps to reproduce -

1. On a touch device (Surface pro 4) with Windows 10 OS Oct 2018 release run this plnkr in the Edge browser
2. Try to touch and scroll simultaneously
3. one of the list-item will turn grey
4. All the list-item will become unresponsive to invoke event and I am able to select multiple list-items and turn them grey
5. If items is invoke-able then the date and time of invocation will be updated under the win-list box. If it is frozen, then the date and time will not update

Comment: This seems to be roughly related to issue raised by WinJS team last year. See https://github.com/winjs/winjs/pull/1660

Comment: Additionally it is found that if the parent container is scroll-able this issue is reproducible easily. But even with parent container not scrolling, if user uses two fingers to touch and scroll then the issue is reproducible nevertheless